# Jquery not working on my Windows 8 Phone app created using HTML 5 template in Visual studio 2012

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am using Visual studio 2012 to create a sample Windows 8 Phone app.

From the "Create New Project" option I have selected,

> Windows > Windows Phone HTML5 App

I have also added a jquery.min.js file to the project as shown below.

[image]

Below is my code written in index.html...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/html/css/phone.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/html/js/jquery.min.js" ></script>
        <title>Windows Phone</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $("#dynamic-box").text("hey !");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>MY APPLICATION</p>
        </div>
        <div id="dynamic-box"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But no matter what I try my jquery code just wont work. Is there some other way in which jquery is to be written in Windows 8 Phone app ?

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things going on here, one jQuery, one Windows Phone:

1. Put your code into the [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event (it won't work in a web page either as is)

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#dynamic-box").text("hey!");
       });
   </script>
   ```
2. Set [IsScriptEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.isscriptenabled%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) BEFORE navigating to the opening page.  Flip the order of the statements in `Browser_Loaded` in `MainPage.xaml.cs`.

   ```
   private void Browser_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       // Add your URL here
       Browser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
       Browser.Navigate(new Uri(MainUri, UriKind.Relative));
   }
   ```

Comment: Also, you'll need to use a MS approved version of jQuery.
You can add it to your project by using the NuGet package manager (Project> Manage NuGet Packeges).

Answer (score 1):

I recently w[rote a post](http://yassershaikh.com/windows-8-phone-development-how-to-use-jquery-using-html-5-template-in-visual-studio-2012/) on this, thought it be useful to share it here...

**Step 1 : Add jquery.min.js to the solution**

[image]

**Step 2 : Change the order of statement in `Browser_Loaded` method as shown below**

```
private void Browser_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Add your URL here
    Browser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
    Browser.Navigate(new Uri(MainUri, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

**Step 3: Sample Jquery code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/html/css/phone.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/html/js/jquery.min.js" ></script>
        <title>Windows Phone</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#message").text("Welcome !");

          $("#goBtn").click(function(){
            $("#message").text("button has been pressed");
          });
        });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>MY APPLICATION</p>
        </div>
        <div id="message"></div>
        <input type="button" id="goBtn" value="press me !" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I like the full featured answer. Can you create an edited update for phonegap/Cordova v3?